Why did Krishna not mention Pradyumna as an Atiratha if Yudhishthira did?
The following words of Krishna to Yudhishthira do not mention Pradyumna as an Atiratha.

In our race, O king, there are full eighteen thousand brothers and
cousins. Ahuka hath had a hundred sons, each of whom is almost like
a god (in prowess), Charudeshna with his brother Chakradeva, Satyaki,
myself, Valadeva the son of Rohini, and my son Samva who is equal unto
me in battle--these seven, O king are Atirathas. Besides these,
there are others, O king, whom I shall presently name. They are
Kritavarman, Anadhrishti, Samika, Samitinjaya, Kanka, Sanku and Kunti.
These seven are Maharathas. There are also two sons of Andhakabhoja,
and the old king himself. Endued with great energy these are all
heroes, each mighty as the thunderbolt.
[Section 14, Rajasuyarambha Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata
]

However, the following words of Yudhishthira to Satyaki imply that Pradyumna is an Atiratha.

Amongst the foremost ones of the Vrishni race, two are regarded as
Atirathas. They are mighty-armed Pradyumna and thyself, O Satwata,
that are so famous.
[Section 109, Jayadratha-Vadha Parva, Drona Parva, The Mahabharata]

In this, Yudhishthira did not mention everyone, but it seems that Krishna provided a comprehensive account. In this context, I want to know the reason why Krishna did not mention the name of Pradyumna.

There is a editing mistake in the test. There should be a coma after Charudeshna and his brother.
This is what BORI Says -

Ahuka has one hundred sons and each of them has three hundred more.
Charudeshna and his brother, Chakradeva, Satyaki, I myself, Rohini’s son, Samba who matches Shouri in battle—these are the seven
atirathas.


238 (13), Mantra parva, Mahabharata.

Here Charudeshna's brother is referring to Pradyumna. Both Charudeshna and Pradyumna are sons of Rukmini.
